# How to do Aggregate and Max function around a dynamic range in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table listed as below. I need to find 2 items here.

1. Maximum Passenger Count
2. Maximum Count of Passenger+Seat

[image]

To Achieve this, I have written formulas below. Also please note that I am taking this result from sheet name Calculation. The data is there in Bus  sheet

For first case the formulas is as below

```
Max('Bus'!C7:'Bus'!C8)
```

And for the second case

```
Aggregate(14,6,'Bus'!B7:'Bus'!B8+'Bus'!C7:'Bus'!C8,1)
```

So my problem here is that this bus tabl is dynamic. It grows more or less sometime. So how do I make these formulas dynamic.Please advise

Comment: Isn't `Max('Bus'!C7:'Bus'!C8)` really just `Max('Bus'!C7:'C8)`?

Answer (score 2):

This is for the `=Max()` option:

`=MAX(C7:C1048576)`

Simply use the last cell with pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>.

You do not need to refer `Bus` in the formula `=Max('Bus'!C7:'Bus'!C8)` at all, `=Max(C7:C8)` is ok, if you are working on the `Bus` worksheet. On any other sheet, `=MAX('Bus'!C7:C8)` would be enough.

Comment: If working on the `Calculate` sheet it would be `=MAX('Bus'!C7:C8)`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - that's true.

Comment: Thanks and can you help with second formula

Comment: @user3428508 - for the second formula, the answer of Jeeped works pretty nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=Max('Bus'!C7:index('Bus'!C:C, match(1e99, 'Bus'!C:C)))
=Aggregate(14, 6, 'Bus'!B7:index('Bus'!B:B, match(1e99, 'Bus'!B:B))+
                  'Bus'!C7:index('Bus'!C:C, match(1e99, 'Bus'!B:B))
```

Your own aggregate function is a little confusing since column B goes to row 8 but column C only goes to row 7.

Comment: The `1e99` is a great feature! :) It is really worthy to explain it a bit :)

Comment: @Vityata same as `=1E+99` a very big number. It's a one with 99 zeros.

Comment: `1e99` is a very large number; literally a 1 followed by 99 zeroes. `match(1e99, 'Bus'!B:B)` returns the row number of the last number in column B.

Comment: I like how `=IFERROR(MATCH(E1+99,A:A),0)` gives the last used cell (and 0 for no cell at all). Never had to find use like this in Excel, usually doing it through VBA.

Comment: @Vityata, only the last number. For the last text you would use `match("zzz", 'Bus'!B:B)`

Comment: @Jeeped - then I guess something like this is quite ok - `=MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(E1+99,A:A),0),IFERROR(MATCH("zzz",A:A),0))`?

Comment: Yes that looks like it should cover all situations.

Comment: @Jeeped - not all situations, but it is interesting - I have asked a question for last row, when it is an error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875572/get-the-last-row-of-a-column-in-excel-without-vba

Comment: @Jeeped: if the column contains a character, this is not returning the correct result - MATCH(E1+99,A:A)

Comment: please read the comments or refer to one of my many other responses on this subject.