# Get the last row of a column in Excel, without VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In general, getting the last row of a given column in Excel is easily done with a User-Defined Function in VBA:

```
Function lastRow(wsName As String, Optional columnToCheck As Long = 1) As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(wsName)
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnToCheck).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

For the last row there are two excel formulas I found so far:

- `=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A:A<>"")*ROW(A:A)))`
- `=MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(E1+99,A:A),0),IFERROR(MATCH("zzz",A:A),0))`

**The problem** with them is that the first does not work, if there is an error in the range and the second does not return the real last row, if it is an error, but the last non-error row, thus returning 6 and not 7:

[image]

**The question** is how to get a formula that returns 7, as this is the last row in column A that is used? Although, it is an error. Without VBA.

Comment: `=MAX(IFERROR(A:A<>"",1)*ROW(A:A))` but it is an array formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner - yes, it seems it works quite well. Any chance to avoid the ctrl+shift part?

Comment: Which is why I put it in a comment, did not think you wanted that need.  But looks like you got an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one (without an array formula)

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))),ROW(A:A))
```

**How does it work?**

1. `NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))` returns an array of `True` and `False`
2. `1/(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))` then 1 divided by that array results in another array of `1` or `#DIV/0!` which is used as `lookup_vector`
3. We use `2` as `lookup_value` which cannot be found because the largest value in the `lookup_array` is `1`, so lookup will match the last `1` in the array.
4. As `result_vector` we use `ROW(A:A)` to get the row number of the last used cell
   (alternatively use `A:A` to get the value instead of the row number).

Comment: Even `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))),ROW(A:A)),0)`, to make it work with no values :)

Comment: Quite a good one. Btw, found quite a good article, that even gives the value - https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell

Comment: Value is even easier you just need to omit the `ROW` part: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))),A:A)`

Comment: Amazing. Is it possible to get the last row number of any column within the worksheet? I mean the MAX last number regardless the column

Comment: @YasserKhalil use `=SUMMENPRODUKT((MAX(WENNFEHLER(((A:C)<>"");WAHR)*ZEILE(A:A))))` to find the last used row in column A to C. Add the formula as array formula using ctrl+shift+enter. Note that this will make your worksheet slow as there have to be done a lot of calculations with sumproduct. VBA would be much quicker here.

Comment: @YasserKhalil sorry my bad: `=SUMPRODUCT((MAX(IFERROR(((A:C)<>"");TRUE)*ROW(A:A))))` • Also try `=MAX(IFERROR(A:C<>"",1)*ROW(A:A))` this should work too and might be faster.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MAX(IFERROR(((A:A)<>"");TRUE)*ROW(A:A))))
```

**Remember** that this formula needs to be entered with <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

`(A:A) <> ""` : checks for not empty cells and returns `TRUE` if not empty.
`(IFERROR(((A:A)<>"");TRUE)` : checks for not empty cells and returns `TRUE` if not empty, if an error is detected it returns also `TRUE`.

Rest of code works as before.

More info about the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> combination can be found here: [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

Comment: Hi Laurens, thank you for your answer. This looks very similar to the formula in the comments by @Scott Craner, just complicating it a bit with `=SUMPRODUCT()`.